# JPQL Query Bulk UPDATE SET on an ElementCollection field

Tags: jpa, jpql, bulkupdate

I have the following JPA Entity I want to update:

```
@Entity(name = "EmployeeImpl")
@Table(name = "EmployeeImpl")
public class EmployeeImpl {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "employeeId")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @ElementCollection
  private List<String> phonenumber;
}
```

I thought I use a `namedQuery` like so

```
@NamedQuery(name = "updateEmployee",
    query = "Update EmployeeImpl e SET e.phonenumber :number WHERE e.id = :id")
```

But that doesn't work: `Exception Description: Error compiling the query [updateEmployee: Update EmployeeImpl e SET e.phonenumber = :number WHERE e.id = :id], line 1, column 28: invalid access of attribute [phonenumber] in SET clause target [e], only state fields and single valued association fields may be updated in a SET clause.`

Question is, how do I update an `@ElementCollection`? If it's possible i'd like to do it with a jpql query.

Comment: Do you want to update the whole list of numbers or simply add a number?

Comment: I am interested in both. The query I posted is supposed to replace all numbers with the new values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible in JPQL. As kostja says: the message says it clear and also according to the JPA specification, Chapter "4.10 Bulk Update and Delete Operations" you may update only state fields and single values object fields.

> The syntax of these operations is as follows:

```
update_statement ::= update_clause [where_clause]
update_clause ::= UPDATE entity_name [[AS] identification_variable]
                  SET update_item {, update_item}*

update_item ::= [identification_variable.]{state_field | single_valued_object_field} =    new_value

new_value ::=
scalar_expression |
simple_entity_expression |
NULL
```

**WHAT TO DO?**

Probably the most clean way to do that is simply to fetch the entities and to add/replace the phone number/s, although you can always do that also with [Native Queries](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29), i.e SQL queries as kostja says.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the failure is stated in the error message. You cannot use bulk updates on non-singular attributes of your entity, since they are stored in a different table.

How do you do it instead? You update the collection table.

The default table name for collection tables is `<parent_entity>_<field_name>`. So the table you are interested in should be named `EmployeeImpl_phonenumber`. The `id` column for the `EmployeeImpl` (the foreign key) should be named `EmployeeImpl_id` per default.

**EDIT** What I posted initially was not valid in JPQL. You might want to use a native query instead. It is simple, so it should be portable:

The native query could then look like this:

```
UPDATE EmplyeeImpl_phonenumber 
SET phonenumber = ? 
WHERE employeeimpl_id = ?
```

Comment: No, its from the top of my head. If it does not work, I'll delete the answer. But you are probably right , I am mixing JPQL and native SQL.

Comment: I get errors while compiling that query: `Unknown entity type [EmployeeImpl_phonenumber]`
I guess I can't update something that is not an entity, at least not like that.

Comment: Right, then you are probably bound to use native SQL

Comment: I don't think I can. This has to work on at least H2 and PostgreSQL.