# Bulk Insert Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have an entities defined as:

```
class Group {

    // some irrelevant fields

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=User.class)
    private List<User> users;
}

class User {

    // some irrelevant fields

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=Group.class)
    private List<Group> groups;
}
```

In my interface, I'm trying to provide a way to add users to a group in a sort of bulk-entry form. Is there a way to allow the insertion of a new many-to-many entry, without having to load the entire collection of users in a group first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the side has to be the inverse side, using `mappedBy`. You just need to update the owner side.

So if you make `User` the owner side, you just need to add the group to the user.

If that is not sufficient, then consider using SQL.

Also, `targetEntity` is redundant with the generic type of the list. You don't need it.

Comment: It'd be a similar problem going the other way. Since it's a bulk-entry form, there could really be 20+ users to update easily. They'd all have to be queried, then persisted after adding the group. Looks like I will have to use SQL directly here.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that with JPQL, although you did not define "in a sort of bulk-entry form". Basically you either use Native Queries (i.e SQL queries) or fetch the whole collections. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246757/jpql-query-bulk-update-set-on-an-elementcollection-field/20247326#20247326) for details.