# @Query Spring Data JPA Update Not Working

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

> Here is my User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements IBaseEntity<User> {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long userId;

@Column(unique = true)
@NotNull
private String username;

@Column(unique = true)
@NotNull
private String email;

@Column
@NotNull
private String password;

// @formatter:off
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "users_roles", 
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, 
           inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
// @formatter:on
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();

@Column
@NotNull
private Boolean locked;

...



}
```

> Here is my Role entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role implements IBaseEntity<Role> {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long roleId;

@Column(unique = true)
@NotNull
private String name;

...

}
```

> Here is my User service:

```
package org.quickloanconnect.service;

public interface IUsersService extends IBaseService<User>{

    public void updateUserRolesById(List<Role> roles, Long userId);

    ...

}
```

> Here is the UserServiceImpl :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UsersServiceImpl  extends AbstractServiceImpl<User> implements    
IUsersService {

...

@Override
@Transactional
public void updateUserRolesById(List<Role> roles, Long user_id) {
    userDao.updateUserRolesById(roles, user_id);
}

...

}
```

> And here is the dao:

```
public interface IUsersDao {

...

@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE User u SET u.roles = :roles WHERE u.userId = :userId")
public void updateUserRolesById(@Param("roles") List<Role> roles,   
@Param("userId") Long userId);

...
}
```

> When I run this update, I get the following: SqlExceptionHelper   : No value specified for parameter 2 . What is causing this? When I update my user with a single role, I see that a List of size one is getting to the dao with the correct userId (both parameters present), but the update seems to fail at the dao level with the "SqlExceptionHelper   : No value specified for parameter 2" error message.

Comment: Not possible to uplate a collection using JPQL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246757/jpql-query-bulk-update-set-on-an-elementcollection-field

Comment: interesting. did not know this. how is it done otherwise?

Comment: maybe retrieve the user and then set the roles collection via setter then save again?

Comment: here it is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573023/how-spring-data-jpa-decides-to-call-entitymanager-persist-or-entitymanager-me

Comment: I will award you the credit if you supply your comment in an answer @Alan Hay